# mongodb dot notation find

Tags: java, mongodb

finding a record with dot notation is possible via mongo shell for example:

```
db.events.find({'events.eid':307215649389788})
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing with java drivers, problem is:

- db.getCollection(collectionName).find(query) - expects query as a DBObject.
- when creating DBObject with 'events.eid' as key, the constructor adds "" so I get the following result : "'events.eid'" as key which won't work (also in shell).

how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying, but this works:

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("events.eid", 307215649389788));
```

You need to use double quotes (`"`) with Java strings so if you're using single quotes that's your problem.