# retrieve values from nested json array in mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

My mongo collection has entries in the following format

```
{
    "myobj" : {
        "objList" : [
            { "location" : "Texas" },
            { "location" : "Houston"},
            { "name":"Sam" }
        ]
    }, 
    "category" : "cat1"
}


{
"myobj" : 
{
    "objList" : [
        { "location" : "Tennesy" },
        { "location" : "NY"},
        { "location" : "SF" }
    ]
}, 
"category" : "cat2"

}
```

I want to extract the `"**category**"` where `location` is `"Houston"`. In case of simple JSON object I have to just pass it as query like:

```
BasicDBObject place = new BasicDBObject();
place.put("location", "Houston");
```

But in case of nested JSON I don't know how to pass it as a query and get the appropriate **category**. ie If I pass my location as"Houston" then it should return it's appropriate category "cat1"...i hope my question is clear now....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, you have your documents:

```
db.coll1.insert({
    "myobj" : {
        "objList" : [
            { "location" : "Texas" },
            { "location" : "Houston"},
            { "name":"Sam" }
        ]
    }, 
    "category" : "cat1"
})
```

and

```
db.coll1.insert({
    "myobj" : {
        "objList" : [
            { "location" : "Tennesy" },
            { "location" : "Houston"},
            { "location" : "SF" }
        ]
    }, 
    "category" : "cat1"
})
```

Now you can find what you want using the [dot operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

`db.coll1.find({"myobj.objList.location": "Texas"}).pretty()` will return one object which has Texas

`db.coll1.find({"myobj.objList.location": "SF"}).pretty()` will return one object which has SF

`db.coll1.find({"myobj.objList.location": "Houston"}).pretty()` will return both objects

And now I hope you will be able to write it in Java. I have never used Java, but [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13896567/1090562) you can do something like this. If it will not work, just look how to use dot operator in java driver for mongo:

```
DBCursor cursor = coll1.find(new BasicDBObject("myobj.objList.location", "Texas"));
```

**P.S.** you told, that you wanted to retrieve category. In such a way, you will need to use a projection `db.coll1.find({<the query I provided}, {category: 1, _id: 0})`

Comment: yeah it works fine @Salvador...+1 for your helping hand